# What do chimpz/bonobos/orangutangs/gorillas feed their babies with?

Tags: reproduction, food, mammals, milk

I just read this [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50446/what-did-babies-eat-before-the-advent-of-modern-blenders) and it made me curious about what a more original baby diet would look like. So, at what age do our closest relatives in the animal kingdom start giving their offspring more solid food, in addition to milk, and how do they prepare it?

Comment: You are expected to show some attempt to answer the question on your own. go on google scholar and type in chimp weening diet.

Comment: @John I googled but it was hard to find relevant keywords.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3581971/